# how to programatically select data from a stored proc for a dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a drop down list that is populated by a stored proc..

It has pulled back all the data in that table, but i would only like to show a few on the list.. how is it possible to just select a couple of them via inputting the id numbers.. i have something like this at the moment but it doesnt work...

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = mgr.GetItemSeriesMaster();.DefaultView.RowFilter("ID = 201");
```

And my final question is once populated my grid view is not changing to the selected item in the list... when my aspx site refreshes the data does not change.. does anybody know how to fix this so that it changes when i select a different item..

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ.

```
 List<YourList> _filteredList = _originalList.Where(x => x.ID = 201).ToList();
 DropDownList1.DataSource  = _filteredList;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i am pretty new to coding, i have added the code but i get red error underneath the <yourlist> and _originallist... what needs to be input into these or do i need to create a variable for them.. im not sure

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are using DataView-- Rowfilter which is the correct approach. For GrIdView to Change Content on DropDownList Selection change, you need to set AutoPostBack of the Dropdownlist to true and bind the GridView in the DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you right you need to add [ListControl.TextChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) so  changes to your grid will occur when you select a different item.